# seaborn staked count bar plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have survey data with passenger points for services as an example.

I am trying to make a plot for each service where points are stacked in a bar with their percentage. I need to use hue='Haul'

I am failing to create the plot

[image]

Full column names are:

```
ordinal_cols = ['Inflight wifi service','Departure/Arrival time convenient', 'Ease of Online booking','Gate location', 'Food and drink', 'Online boarding', 'Seat comfort','Inflight entertainment', 'On-board service', 'Leg room service','Baggage handling', 'Checkin service', 'Inflight service','Cleanliness', 'Haul']
```

I am trying to count by points for each service and make a stacked bar with their percentage (total column percentage: 100). I also want to show each service broken down by `'Haul'`

I mean, I want x cord shown by haul and y cord shown as stacked bars for each haul

Like this but bar present %a 0, %b 1, %c 2, %d 3, %e 4, %f 5

I appreciate the help. Thank you

[Edit: I uploaded the data and what I could.] [1](https://github.com/Decaf76/Airline_Passenger_services_satisfaction)

I want to make it as follows:

[![enter image description here]] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey9S0.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey9S0.png)

Comment: Please provide your input data in a reproducible format, not an image. Also provide a schematic of the expected graph for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for response I uploaded original data and what I tried in github

Comment: Please add the essence of the code and some test data here, inside the post.  Stackoverflow is meant to be a repository to be used during many years, while the github repro probably will change soon.  Note that seaborn doesn't have an option to stack bars (because seaborn's author considers stacked bars a visualization to be avoided, and because stacked bars get confusing when used together with error bars).

Comment: Seaborn's histplot does have an option to stack (`multiple='stack'`) or to fill until 100% (`multiple='fill'`). Something like `sns.histplot(x='haul', hue='inflight wifi', multiple='fill')`.